# Создание git репозитория, состоящего из разных папок

Tags: git, git-submodule

Только осваиваю `git`, возник вопрос, на который я не могу найти в поисковике ответ. Возможно, я не правильно формулирую саму задачу.

Есть такая структура в папке моего локального веб-сервера

```
server_folder  
--my_project_logic  
--localhost  
----my_project_webresource  
----othersite1  
----othersite2  
----...
```

Мне надо создать один репозиторий с 2 папками `my_project_logic` и `my_project_webresource`, которые находятся на разных уровнях вложенности.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где лучше инициализировать репозиторий?

Пока придумалось только одно решение - инициализировать репозиторий на папку `server_folder`, и в `.gitignore` прописать исключение на все, кроме этих двух папок. Есть ли решения поизящнее?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я правильно понимаю, что othersite1 - это совсем другой проект и мешать с Вашим его не нужно, а папка server_folder находиться в папке вебсервера? Это чревато проблемами в будущем. К примеру, захотите делать деплой через git (просто сделав pull),  а это очень плохо - даже [yandex](http://habrahabr.ru/post/70330/) на это натыкался.

Хорошо сделать так. В домашнем каталоге делается папка с проектом, где все хранится. В результате развернуть там git не будет проблем - все будет только от одного проекта. А дальше делается скрипт, который с помощью rsync или других утилит копирует файлы по местам. Понятно, что для разработчика все копировать постоянно - накладно, поэтому, можно просто создать две симлинки (собственно это скрипт также может делать).

Но если пойти ещё дальше, то лушче сделать так. Под проект заводиться виртуальное окружение (lxc, docker, rocket или просто virtualbox). В результате на одно окружение будет один проект и не будет никаких проблем.

Comment: Да, ответ на оба первых вопроса - утвердительный. server_folder в частности - это есть папка OpenServer, где ко всему прочему размещен и сам веб-сервер.  По предложенному решению - спасибо с симлинками - класс, буду разбираться, у меня тут Win 7, но, наверно, большой разницы не будет.  Второе решение - это следующая ступень эволюции для меня, но поэкспериментировать можно будет - virtualbox  :)

Comment: Не успела поправить прошлый коммент, окончание коммента так и повисло в воздухе. В общем, решение с симлинками - просто отличное. Очень благодарна за подсказку.